# SQL: count and sum based on conditions from the related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables;

**countries(id, name, region);**

```
1, 'UK', '1';
2, 'USA', '1';
3, 'AUSTRALIA', '1';
4, 'CHINA', '0';
5, 'INDIA', '0';
6, 'SRI LANKA', '0' ;
```

and

**tickets(id, country_id, issued_date, holder, gender, fee, canceled);**

```
100, 2, 2017-08-15, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '1';
101, 2, 2017-08-15, 'Person 2', 'M', 200, '0';
103, 3, 2017-08-15, 'Person 3', 'M', 200, '0';
104, 5, 2017-08-16, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '0';
105, 6, 2017-08-16, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '0';
106, 1, 2017-08-17, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '0';
107, 3, 2017-08-18, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '1';
108, 4, 2017-08-18, 'Person 1', 'M', 200, '0';
```

I want to group all the tickets based on `issued_date` with some aggregates fields to generate the summary. Here is my query:-

```
SELECT

issued_date,
COUNT(*) as total_tickets,
COUNT(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as issued_tickets,
SUM(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN fee ELSE NULL END) as total_amount

FROM tickets

GROUP BY issued_date;
```

But, how to use COUNT and SUM for related table countries? For example, I want to show how many tickets were sold on a date (2017-08-15) from a country having region = '1'.

I tried the following, but the results are not correct for region_1 field

```
SELECT

issued_date,
COUNT(*) as total_tickets,
COUNT(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as issued_tickets,SUM(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN fee ELSE NULL END) as total_amount,
(SELECT COUNT(countries.id) FROM countries WHERE countries.id = tickets.country_id && countries.region = '1') as region_1

FROM tickets

GROUP BY issued_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a derived table that is grouped on issue_date, country_id and region and use that derived table in an inner join.

```
SELECT issued_date
    ,COUNT(*) AS total_tickets
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS issued_tickets
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN canceled = '0' THEN fee ELSE NULL END) AS total_amount
    ,tickets_by_region.total_region_1_tickets
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT issued_date
        ,country_id
        ,countries.region
        ,COUNT(*) AS total_region_1_tickets
    FROM tickets
    INNER JOIN countries ON (countries.id = tickets.country_id)
    GROUP BY issued_date
        ,countries.country_id
        ,countries.region
    ) tickets_by_region ON (
        tickets_by_region.issued_date = tickets.issued_date
        AND tickets_by_region.country_id = tickets.country_id
        AND tickets_by_region.region = '1'
        ) AS region_1
GROUP BY issued_date;
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and [GROUP BY with HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) which allow append next table on related keys and add to additional summary or counts you need to use them like sub-query because they need to work with no filtered data.

> Approach is prepare data in sub-query and then JOIN the filtered data
>   to your main table which can do final filtering for final result.

SQL can looks like bellow (tested on local)

```
SELECT t1.issued_date, COUNT(t1.id) as sum_tickets, t2.region, t3.total_tickets
FROM tickets t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(id) as total_tickets FROM tickets) t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN countries t2 ON t2.id = t1.country_id
GROUP BY t1.issued_date
HAVING (t2.region = '1')
```

Output is

issued_date, sum_tickets, region, total_tickets
2017-08-15,       3,                          1,             8
2017-08-17,       1,                          1,             null
2017-08-18,       2,                 1,             null

You can add more conditions to HAVING in query.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use conditional aggregation with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.issued_date, COUNT(*) as total_tickets,
       SUM(t.canceled = 0) as issued_tickets,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.canceled = 0 THEN t.fee END) as total_amount,
       SUM(c.region = 1) as num_region_1
FROM tickets t JOIN
     countries c
     ON t.country_id = c.id
GROUP BY t.issued_date;
```